# Problem in implement "YouTube like motion Example" for MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, transition, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

when I wanna implement YouTube like motion Example from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples) I got some error. here are my XML codes.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:context=".presentation.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".presentation.activities.MainActivity">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


        <com.dastangram.app.presentation.components.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/place_holder"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/media_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/media_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_radius_lower"
            android:visibility="visible" />



        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:theme="@style/BottomNavigation"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
                app:menu="@menu/mnu_bottom_navigation"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_layout">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <EditText
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_color"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_radius"
                android:textColorHint="@color/color_text_color"
                android:hint="@string/str_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
                android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_main"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color_text_color"/>


    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

fragment_media_player.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_24"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrains_media"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_media_cover"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14999998"/>


    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fast_forward"
            android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_fast_next"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_sec_forward"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_forward_30_black"
            android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_sec_forward"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play_pause_view"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_fast_next"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <com.ohoussein.playpause.PlayPauseView
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            app:fill_color="#e1e1e1"
            app:pause_bg="@color/color_back_box"
            app:play_bg="@color/color_text_color"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_sec_back"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_sec_forward"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_replay_10_black"
            android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_sec_back"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_fast_prev"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play_pause_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fast_rewind"
            android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_fast_prev"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_sec_back"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"/>


    <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:tint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_page"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_media_desc"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_media"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:progressTint="@color/color_text_color"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="#4d34ff"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

scene_24.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by motionlicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:interpolator="linear">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/constrains_media"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp" />

        <ConstraintSet android:id="@id/start">

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/constrains_media"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_media_cover"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constrains_media"
                />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_media_desc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_fast_next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <Constraint android:id="@id/play_pause_view" >
                <PropertySet motion:alpha="0" />
            </Constraint>

            <Constraint android:id="@id/img_fast_prev" >
                <PropertySet motion:alpha="0" />
            </Constraint>

            <!--<Constraint
                android:id="@id/bottom_nav"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />-->
        </ConstraintSet>

        <ConstraintSet android:id="@id/end">

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/constrains_media"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_media_cover"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:2.5"
                />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_media_desc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/img_fast_next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constrains_media"
                />

            <Constraint android:id="@id/play_pause_view" >
                <PropertySet motion:alpha="1" />
            </Constraint>

            <Constraint android:id="@id/img_fast_prev" >
                <PropertySet motion:alpha="1" />
            </Constraint>


            <!--<Constraint-->
                <!--android:id="@id/bottom_nav"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"-->
                <!--motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
                <!--motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"-->
                <!--motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />-->
        </ConstraintSet>

        <KeyFrameSet>

            <KeyPosition
                motion:target="@id/img_media_cover"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:percentX="0"
                motion:curveFit="linear"
                />

            <KeyPosition
                motion:target="@id/constrains_media"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:curveFit="linear"
                />

            <KeyPosition
                motion:target="@id/img_media_desc"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:curveFit="linear"
                />

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="75"
                motion:target="@id/img_fast_next" />

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0.10"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:target="@id/img_fast_prev" />

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0.10"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:target="@id/play_pause_view" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

in activity_main.xml I use two frameLayout to show two different fragments. one of them for fragment_main.xml and another one for fragment_media_holder.xml. I want to like "YouTube like motion Example" when swiping up I see all Media Player part and when swiping bottom just see img_cover and playPauseView and ProgressBar. my please help me found bug in my code ?! 
thank you